# Getline in class c++

Tags: c++, class, methods, getline

I am trying to write a getline function that will take in a string of words from an open stream...I have looked on different websites and tried what it says to do, but I am getting tons of weird errors. I need the getline to take in all of the words in the "contents" section of my file. This is what I have tried, but I am getting errors with this.

```
// Fill a single Tweet from a stream (open file)
// Returns true if able to read a tweet; false if end of file is encountered
// Assumes that each line in the file is correct (no partial tweets)
bool Tweet::FillTweet(ifstream &Din)
{
   string tmp;

   bool Success = false;
   Din >> tmp;
   if (!Din.eof())
   {
      Success = true;
      date = tmp;
      Din >> hashtag >> getline(Din,contents);
   }
   else
      cout << "I don't want to read your tweet anyway. " << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the incorrect way to use `getline()`. Change to:

```
Din >> hashtag;
getline(Din,contents);
```

Why? `getline()` returns a reference to `istream`. There is no overloaded `>>` operator that takes two `istream`s

Answer (score 1):

This

```
  Din >> hashtag >> getline(Din,contents);
```

needs to be:

```
  Din >> hashtag;
  getline(Din, contents);
```

I would also do

```
if (Din >> tmp)
```

instead of `if (!Din.eof)`

Comment: Can you explain why you would change if(!Din.eof)?

Comment: Because you are avoiding an extra check - and you won't get an infinite loop if `date` can't be read but it's not EOF. (Although that is unlikely with a string, of course)

Comment: [Because of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Checking your io's instead of assuming they're proper is *always* a good idea.